# $_POST is NULL in php retrieve form page

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't understand why I have NULL value in php result form page

**FORM PAGE:**

```
 <FORM action="include/scripts/result.php" method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="name4">test value: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="name4"><BR>

<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</P>
</FORM>
```

**RETRIEVE FORM PAGE:**

```
<?php 
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name4']);
    var_dump($_POST['name4']);
    die();
 ?>
```

As result I have **NULL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are relying solely on the id attribute only.

POST requires a name attribute:

```
<INPUT type="text" id="name4" name="name4">
```

Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have given you an undefined index name4 warning.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you, Fred. Really supportive comment.